# Merged row cells in generated excel report

Tags: excel, report, rtf, bi-publisher

I'm trying to fix the merging of the rows in the generated report from the RTF. I have done already the ff:

1. Set the table properties in the RTF to Auto fit to contents - didn't work
2. Redo the whole RTF file. (Retype everything and assign each field again) - didn't work

Kindly share your thoughts on this? Thanks a lot!
Please see attached photo for reference.

[image]

[RTF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIvb3.gif)

Comment: Why don't you simply use a single unmergerd row and concatenate the entries in column M with a CHAR(10)?

Comment: It would be nice if you could share what you are expecting, and also the RTF file you are working with, or at least a screen shot of the RTF file in word.

Comment: I was expecting not to see those merged rows. the #363909 in the screenshot should be in row 1259 as well. In RTF, I have attached the affected column for this.

See update.